# How to send message on any Whatsapp number by Whatsapp cloud API

Tags: node.js, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I want to send messages on any Whatsapp number using Whatsapp cloud API. I have configured all setting in Whatsapp API setting provided on meta developer web site. The problem is I need to verify sender (recipient) number before add this number into API request (they allow only 5 numbers in free tier)

[image]

So I want to know, how to send messages without verifying recipient number and how to increase recipient limit form 5 to unlimited. For this do I need to add payment method? What do I need to do? I searched on the web but not getting an answer; please help me.

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "", // sender number
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "first_temp",
        "language": {
            "code": "en"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add any phone number in "to" (sender number) without verifying it on Whatsapp cloud API web site.

Answer (score 0):

to send message on any whatsapp number, first i need to add my own number in whatsapp cloud api ( the number should not have any whatsapp account previously ) then i need to set up payment method after these step i can also setup permanent token by setting up system admin user after these all steps i can send message on any number without any limitation